# how to limit GET api call based on user properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-web-api

I have a many to many relationship between ApplicationUser and a model "Companies"
I want the signed in user to only be able to retrieve documents that are assigned to their company(s).

Using this linq statement

```
   public IEnumerable<DocumentResult> GetDocuments()
    {
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        var user = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        return db.Documents
            .Where(j => j.Company.Name == user.Companies)
            .ToResults();
    }
```

I am getting this

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'ICollection'

Models

```
  public class Company
{
    public Company()
    {
        Users = new HashSet<ApplicationUser>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; } 
}
```

ApplicationUser

```
   public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        Companies = new HashSet<Company>();
    }
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
    public ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string ProfilePicUrl { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: First thought is .Where(j => user.Companies.Contains(j.Company.Name))

Comment: now it is saying cannot convert string to models.company

Comment: SO, is the `j.Company.Name` one of the companies in `user.Companies`? Do you need to select one of those companies in that collection to compare to/or search that collection for a match for example?

Comment: i updated the post with both models. yes, each document has a single Company name to it. Each user can be assigned one or more Companys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using code like this:

```
db.Documents
        .Where(j => user.Companies.Any(uc=>uc.Name == j.Company.Name));
        .ToResults();
```

Answer (score -1):

The error msg is clear.

user.Companies is a collection,j.Company.Name is string.

You can not use the "==" to  compare string with the the different type.

Comment: so what do i use to compare?

Comment: This should be a comment. It does not answer the question